# Oscillating solutions of linear o.d.e $y'''+y'=2+\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is solve the differential equation $$y'''(x)+y'(x)=2+\sin x, \ x\geq 0$$ and I get that the general soloution has the form
$y(x)=c_1+c_2\cos x+c_3\sin x+ 2x-\frac{1}{2}x\sin x,\ x\geq 0$.
I see that the part soloution $f(x)=2x-\frac{1}{2}x\sin x$ is not oscillating, because $f(x)=0 \iff x=0$. However how can I proof that this differential equation has or hasn't oscillating solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you wanted.
Since
$$ c_2\cos x+c_3\sin x\ge-\sqrt{c_2^2+c_3^2},2x-\frac12 x\sin x\ge 2x-\frac1 2x=\frac32x $$
for $x\ge0$, so
$$ y(x)=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x+2x-\frac12 x\sin x\ge\frac3 2x+c_1-\sqrt{c_2^2+c_3^2}. $$
Thus for $x>|c_1-\sqrt{c_2^2+c_3^2}|$, $y(x)>\frac12x>0$; namely $y(x)$ is not oscillating.

Comment: $c_1,c_2,c_3$ is every possible real numbers. So, how exactly for large $x\geq 0, \frac3 2x+c_1-\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}>0$? If for example $x=1000000$, I choose $c_1=0$ and $c_2$ with $\sqrt{c_2^2}>\frac{3}{2}1000000$.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: So, every time that $c_1,c_2,c_3$ is changing I constrict to an interval $[x_0,+\infty)$, with $ x_0=x_0(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and then the solution becomes positive.

Comment: Yes, I think so.